# Best way to implement a callgate?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32

I'm programming for an stm32 with [firewall](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00493651-introduction-to-stm32-microcontrollers-security-stmicroelectronics.pdf#page=35). To open the firewall a callgate must be used. The more or less usual way is to write a function with variable arguments and use the first argument in a switch statement to switch between different functions.

```c
int function1_outside(int arg1)
{
    int status;
    // disable interrupts
    status = CallGate(ID1, arg1);
    // enable interrupts
    return status;
}

int CallGate(FunctionID eID, ...)
{
    va_list arguments;
    int status;

    /* Initializing arguments to store all values */
    va_start(arguments, PrimaskParam);

    switch (eID)
    {
        case ID1:
        {
            int arg1;
            /* Retrieve argument(s) */
            arg1 = va_arg(arguments, int);
            // Call the real function
            status = function1_inside(arg1);
            break;
        }
        case ID2:
        {
            // do more ...
            break;
        }
    }

    /* Clean up arguments list*/
    va_end(arguments);

    return status;
}

int function1_inside(int arg1)
{
    int result;
    // do stuff
    result = arg1 + 1;
    return result;
}
```

The biggest problem with this approach is keeping all parts in sync.
Is there a good way to reduce the parts that need to be kept in sync?

Comment: From my naive point of view, you could use a function pointer as the first argument and a void pointer as the second argument, allowing you to select the function using a pointer to the function and allowing you to pass a struct of the parameters as the second parameter, could you not? That would minimize the parts to be held in sync.

Comment: I have already thought in a similar direction. One problem is to get the function pointers. The part with the callgate is compiled separately. You have to transfer the function pointers in advance via the callgate or before activating the firewall. But you also have to maintain the structure with the pointers.

Comment: And another thing is how do I cast from one function with va_list to multiple normal functions?

Comment: Does the CallGate _have to be_ variadic? Otherwise, you could declare it as `void CallGate(void (*function)(void*), void* data)`, therefore accepting the function to call and the parameter to the function. As for getting the function pointer you could on the outside do `extern void function_inside(void*); CallGate(&function_inside, (void*)function_parameters);`

Comment: I suggest to keep the switch to localize the functions, so you with a simple enumeration in an header file can share them between the 2 compilation units. For the parameters declare it as: `extern void CallGate(int code, ...);` in the header. Then declare your sub functions as: `function1_inside(va_list ap);` where `ap` is a pointer to the next argument obtained with: `va_start(ap, code);`. Then in the subfunction you can retrieve all parameters specific to that function.

Comment: After thinking a bit about it, I think it could work. But the number of function parameters is either fixed or a parameter count is used along with switch and typecast.
switch(num_args)
case 1:
`(int(*)(void*))callback`
case 2:
`(int(*)(void*,void*))callback`
To keep it save (the whole point of the firewall) it is necessary to check if the pointer points to the allowed functions.
Eventually at this point the number of arguments can be retreived automatically.

Comment: I would have the inside functions themselves cast and use the supplied void* pointers, so that CallGate does not have to know about the possible parameter types and the functions are pretty contained. To supply more than one arg you can use structs. To check the functions for validity, you can use a function pointer array and check whether the supplied pointer is contained in the array.

Comment: Creating a Call Gate that accepts function pointers defeats the whole purpose of the firewall mechanism, no?

Comment: Why not wrap each function you want to call with an ASM function of identical signature that does the firewall control, then jumps to the original function after returning the registers & stack to the expected state?   That or possible use a SWI?    Everybody seems to focusing on `void*` or function pointers, so maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Or, alternatively, have the wrapper function push the target function address on the stack, save state, do the firewall, restore state, then RTS (which would effectively jump to the function)

Answer (score -1):

I would do an array of function pointers, and would pass any argument via a `void*` argument. Using `stdarg` is confusing, it's better to just do a pointer from the start.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum callgate_func_u {
    CALLGATE_FUNC_THAT_PRINTS_INT,
    CALLGATE_OTHER_FUNC,
    CALLGATE_FUNC_LEN,
};

int function1_inside(int id, void *arg) {
    return printf("%d", *(int*)arg);
}
int function2_inside(int id, void *arg) {
    return printf("%lf", *(float*)arg);
}

/// Represents a function to be called.
/// @param id The ID used to call the function.
/// @param arg A pointer to __any__ user context.
typedef int callgate_func_t(int id, void *arg);
static callgate_func_t *const callgate_functions[CALLGATE_FUNC_LEN] = {
    [CALLGATE_FUNC_THAT_PRINTS_INT] = function1_inside,
    [CALLGATE_OTHER_FUNC] = function2_inside,
};

int callgate(enum callgate_func_u id, void *param) {
    static_assert(sizeof(callgate_functions)/sizeof(*callgate_functions) == CALLGATE_FUNC_LEN, "");
    assert(id < CALLGATE_FUNC_LEN);
    callgate_func_t *const func = callgate_functions[id];
    assert(func != NULL);
    return func(id, param);
}

int function1_outside(int arg1) {
    int status;
    // disable interrupts
    status = callgate(CALLGATE_FUNC_THAT_PRINTS_INT, &arg1);
    // enable interrupts
    return status;
}

int main() {
    printf("5 = ");
    function1_outside(5);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Overall, you might be interested in system calls like `ioctl` and `fcntl`. They are basically doing exactly the same thing, with a big `switch` on the kernel side that chooses proper action depending on id.

Comment: The array with pointers inside seems also to be a good solution.
One thing to note printf needs to interact with the hardware. Calls to functions outside the firewall closes the firewall and when returning trigger the firewall to reset the system. This is the reason why interrupt should be dissabled or a firewall internal interrupt vector table is needed.

Comment: The answer basically makes no or very little sense. DV-ted. @KamilCuk read the STM32 Lx reference manual before answering the questions.

Answer (score -1):

The code is not as important as the correct placement of the `callgate` code.

It has to start execution from the 2-nd word in the protected memory segment. You need to define it in the linker script and then place the function in the correct segment (at position 4 in bytes). All functions called from there have to located in this memory segment (ie to be placed in the protected area address space). So basically - no libraries (unless you modify the linker script to put the code from particular object files into protected address space).

Comment: I know. I build two separate binaries and flash them separately. ST builds the callgate part first and includes it in the linker script of the main part.